# Magento: Location of function renderCategoriesMenuHtml found in top.phtml

Tags: magento, magento-1.5

The top navigation template file at /catalogue/navigation/top.phtml contains just this short function:

```
<?php $_menu = $this->renderCategoriesMenuHtml(0,'level-top') ?>
<?php if($_menu): ?>
<div class="nav-container">
    <ul id="nav">
        <?php echo $_menu ?>   
        </ul>
</div>
<?php endif ?>
```

I'm trying to find the renderCategoriesMenuHtml function so that I can get in and edit the structure of the $_menu result that is called in top.phtml.

The purpose is that I want to slightly edit the structure the menu. It currently comes out in a  ul > li > a > ul > li > a > span in HTML and I want to edit this slightly.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The command

```
$ grep -i -r 'function renderCategoriesMenuHtml' *
```

returns

```
app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Navigation.php
```

which contains

```
public function renderCategoriesMenuHtml($level = 0, $outermostItemClass = '', $childrenWrapClass = '')
...
```

Answer (score 8):

as an alternative, for those who aren't so familiar with `grep`, this file also have a PHPDoc comment:

```
<?php
/**
 * Top menu for store
 *
 * @see Mage_Catalog_Block_Navigation
 */
?>
```

As you can see, it says which class `$this` is refering to in this file, in which you'll find the method you're looking for.

HTH